# Javascript selector with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to add an event listener to 2 buttons. Their ids are:

```
authCreateAcctConfirmNoBtn
authCreateAcctConfirmYesBtn
```

How would I do the following, I imagine I am close:

```
authCreateAcctConfirm(No|Yes)Btn.addEventListener('blur', function() {...
```

I don't know how to tell the browser that the object to attach to is a regular expression?

Comment: you add the click event to a parent element, and in the event, use /theID/.test(e.target.id) to filter out the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the elements first. This is done via [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

I would avoid crazy Regex magic and choose the straightforward way. The easiest solution would look like this:

```
document.querySelector("#authCreateAcctConfirmYesBtn").addEventListener("blur",func);
document.querySelector("#authCreateAcctConfirmNoBtn").addEventListener("blur",func);

function func(){
   /* stuff here */
}
```

To select both at once, you could use `querySelectorAll` and use this selector:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#authCreateAcctConfirmYesBtn, 
                                          #authCreateAcctConfirmNoBtn");
```

You now have to iterate over the returned `NodeList` resultset with a straightforward `for` loop or a borrowed Array method:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements,func);
```

Here you get the element handed over as first parameter in func.

Comment: Since there are 2 buttons, why not just `document.querySelectorAll("#authCreateAcctConfirmYesBtn, #authCreateAcctConfirmNoBtn");`?

Comment: @nhahtdh You are of course absolutely correct, I really dunno why I did it the stupid way;) I thought somehow, that this is not supported by the native querySelector - i blame the time of day;)